# Protobuf Precompiler

Tags: nuget, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

From Visual Studio I have used NuGet to grab the latest protobuf-net library (Version 2.0.0.640). In [**this blog post by Marc Gravell**](http://marcgravell.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/introducing-protobuf-net-precompiler.html), there is a protobuf-net precompiler discussed:

> For example, say I create a new Phone 7 DTO assembly, called PhoneDto (because it is late and I lack imagination). I can then create a serialization assembly via:
>
> ```
> precompile {some path}\PhoneDto.dll –o:PhoneSerializer.dll –t:MySerializer
> ```
>
> This will generate a library called PhoneSerializer.dll, which you can reference from your main project (in addition to the DTO and the protobuf-net core).

I've searched for the `precompile` program in the NuGet package, but it seems like it is missing.

Am I missing something?
Is there a NuGet package that includes the precompiler?
If not, where can I get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The precompile tool is currently only available in the [code.google.com download](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/downloads/list); however, adding a second NuGet package (protobuf-net.tools, or similar) with the command-line utilities is on my todo list.